# How to skip CI/CD step on GitLab depending on if target machine has the file already?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner

From the [official document](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic) from GitLab, it seems that a CI/CD stage can only be skipped based on if a file is changed. Is it possible to skip a step based on if a file / folder exists on the machine to be deployed?

The case is that it is common to use a package management tool. (e.g. composer in PHP or NPM in Node.js) Currently the rule is to check if the respective configuration file is changed (e.g. composer.json for composer or package.json for NPM) to see if it is necessary to run the install step (i.e. `composer install` or `npm install`) However, although it seldom happens, when a new machine is used for deployment, the CI/CD would crash because the install step is skipped.

Currently, the problem is solved by manually trigger the install step, but is it possible to auto detect if the file exists at the hosting machine to  determine if the install step should be run?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a way to do what you describe. The `only/except` feature in GitLab runs on the GitLab server, before any jobs are created. To be able to know if a file already exists on a server, there needs to be a job created and it needs to be assigned to a gitlab runner.

They have this issue, where it looks like it will be possible to start a job and then determine that it should be skipped by using exit codes:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/16733

In the mean time, you can make it so that your install job always runs, and then just use your build scripts to check for this file. From the pipeline view in GitLab, you will always see your install step. The actual job can just skip to do anything if the file already exists, and then you don't need to remember to run the job manually.

Comment: That may be possible for production environment or UAT environment, but for development environment, as it takes time to run the install step, although it is just a few minutes, it is disturbing when there are frequent commits in the development process.

Comment: Then I think I have misunderstood what you are really asking. Is it the machines that are running the gitlab jobs that sometimes have to install dependencies, if they are new machines, but you would like them to not do anything if they are not new machines?

Comment: No, I think you have correct understanding in your original post. What `npm install` or `composer install` do is to download tons of library files from the recorded sources, which takes a few minutes. (And it is a common practise not to include these library files in the repository)  If it is to deploy to a new machine, the runner will need to download the library files even if there are no changes made the the configuration. Else, it saves time to skip the install step.

Comment: Is there some way that you can check that the job is running on a new machine? Maybe checking that `npm` or `composer` have nothing installed? Then you can have a GitLab job that is always started, but you don't install anything on old machines, and instead just show the job as finished. Something like `if (new_machine) { npm install }`. I think that you can get away with not having to trigger any jobs manually then.